# I want to create an application to receive events raised from Windows Application

Tags: window

I want to create an application to receive events raised from Windows Application.

For example, if windows application is minimized(skype), event should be raised in my application. likewise, i want to handle events of windows application in my console application.

Comment: Ok, sounds interesting!

Comment: Yeah! How far did you come in the mean time?